# How to disable the default key behaviour over a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, look-and-feel, keylistener

I am trying to make a JTree that have a specific behaviours when typing characters such as letter, numbers, ponctuation, to apply filters, decorators, etc.

Everything seems to be working fine, but the selection seems to be changing automatically when I type letters and does not behave the same way as my filters. It looks this behaviour is defined in `BasicTreeUI.Handler.keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` and I don't know how to avoid or override easily this behaviour, and in a look-and-feel-independent way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note: I have tried to consume the key event, it did not help.

Comment: So your keys are performing your actions in addition to traversing the nodes? Or are they just traversing the nodes when there is a conflict?

Answer (score 2):

There are [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) present on a `JTree` which react on those key presses. The following code snippet prints out the available bindings in one of the input maps

```
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class TreeActionMap {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JTree tree = new JTree(  );
        InputMap inputMap = tree.getInputMap( JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT );
        KeyStroke[] keyStrokes = inputMap.allKeys();
        for ( KeyStroke keyStroke : keyStrokes ) {
          Object actionCommand = inputMap.get( keyStroke );
          System.out.println( "keyStroke = " + keyStroke );
          System.out.println( "actionCommand = " + actionCommand );
        }
      }
    } );

  }
}
```

So if you loop over all `InputMap` instances and call `clear` on all of them, the `JTree` should no longer react on those key presses

Comment: Thanks, actually this behaviour is defined in BasicTreeUI.Handler which is a KeyListener. It would have been simpler to redefine if it was in key bindings...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
public class MyJTree extends JTree {

    public class MyBasicTreeUi extends BasicTreeUI{
        @Override
        protected KeyListener createKeyListener() {

        return null;
    }
...
    public MyJTree (){
    ...
    setUI(new MyBasicTreeUi());
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to override the `BasicTreeUI.Handler.keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` behavior of `JTree` in a look-and-feel-independent way, try the following code.

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
for(KeyListener kl: tree.getListeners(KeyListener.class)) {
    tree.removeKeyListener(kl);
}
```

Evidently, the UIs do their work by installing KeyListeners into the JTree during construction, so right after constructing your JTree and before adding your own specific behaviors, just remove the KeyListeners that have already been installed.